# Bi-directional association query question: How do you query an owned class's owner using GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

Say you have two domain classes: Authors and Books. Authors can have many Books, but a Book can only have one Author.

```
class Author {
  static hasMany = [Book]
}

class Book {
  static belongsTo = Author
}
```

How do you query is book's author?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
def book = Book.get(1)
book.author
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your code to:

```
class Author {
  static hasMany = [book:Book]
}

class Book {
  static belongsTo = [author:Author]
}
```

then this should work:

```
def book = Book.get(1)
book.author
```

Comment: The user guide explains the difference between the two versions of `belongTo` at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html - one with and one without the reference back to the owning class.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with a situation involving multiple owners? i.e. Changing static belongsTo = [Author, Publisher] into static belongsTo = [author:Author, publisher:Publisher] without incurring build errors

Comment: I am really confused as to why anyone wouldn't want a back reference - thank you so much for the help though